# Freepascal finding eof after reset of a non-empty file

Tags: windows, reset, eof, freepascal

Got me stumped: on Windows, Free Pascal

```
    {... writes text lines to PdfTmp, then ...}
    close(PdfTmp);
    reset(PdfTmp);
    while not eof(PdfTmp) do begin
        readln(PdfTmp,InpLine);
        writeln(ProdFile,InpLine);
    end;
    close(PdfTmp);
```

I've verified that the PdfTmp file is written with the text, but the eof() function returns true on the first call, thus the while block is never executed.

I tried all kinds of tricks with surrounding code to determine whatever else might be causing the failure, including updating my FPC compiler, to no avail. Tests confirm it is the improper eof() function result.

The same code works properly on a Mac. (FreePascal supports various platforms.)

Any other poor soul out there had this evil befall and stall out a nice project? If so, how was it fixed, if it was?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're using the old-style IO functions, instead of the modern-day stream based classes?

Comment: There's no advantage to using them for working on a program originally coded this direct style.

Comment: :-) Clearly there is - there's no issue with Reset and Eof using streams.

Comment: One can't fix a problem by ignoring it.

Comment: Didn't say ignore it. You could move the code into the 21st century, though.

Comment: @KenWhite No reasons to use complex tools to solve simple task.

Comment: I might convert as suggested, after I've finished all the app oriented details that are my focus. But you see, the code works fine on the Mac, which tells me there is a serious bug lurking in the Windows support, either in FPC or Windows itself, or in their interaction. My professional experience and ethics disallow me from simply walking away, leaving the problem to possibly hurt someone else.

Comment: @Abelisto I agree.  Complex tools is why modern-day apps run into multi-megabyte sizes instead of a few kilobytes of efficient code.

Comment: BTW I have feeling that I already seen such problem somewhere. Try to insert `Readln;/ShowMessage('');` (depending on your app UI) between `close(PdfTmp);` and `reset(PdfTmp);`

Comment: Testing as a terminal command line environment. I already inserted "write('Press enter'); readln;" between close() and reset() and also between reset() and while, thinking the IO system wanted time to complete (against all reasoning) or that the compiler or linker might be throwing random bytes into a critical spot in the code, etc.; and interrogating IOresult in several places. Even changing the text in the file. Various combinations of these tricks. Everything functions as it should, except the eof() returns true every time. So weird.

Comment: Ken White: I'll bite, which standard streatming class is generally considered to be a substitute for textfile I/O? Most classes I know at best are good for very simplistic purposes, and don't even allow to configure codepage, eoln character etc. I don't mind suggesting other options, but at the very least come with a real solution, not vague allegations and subjective labels as "21st century"

Comment: Lor: try to put a multi second sleep close and reset. Reset performs the actual open, and Windows tends to keep locks for a while after closing

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort (also to Lor and KenWhite) Using `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` is a "comme il faut" for every utility on Linux at least :)

Comment: Marco: I will try that. And thank you for the specific suggestion and rationale.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I solved the problem:

```
{}
{$ifdef WIN}

procedure starttext (var F :file; var Feof :boolean);
begin
    reset(F,1); Feof := filesize(F) = 0;
end;

procedure gettext (var F :file; Feoln :array of byte; var Feof :boolean; var S :string);
{ gets the next text line from F into S. Returns false at end of file.
It returns the last string and sets eof if there are no additional strings.}
var  endline, endfile :boolean;  P, R :longint; C, D :byte;
begin
    S := '';
    endline := false;
    endfile := false;
    repeat
        P := filepos(F);
        blockread(F,C,1,R);
        if R = 0 then begin
            endline := true;
            endfile := true; end
        else begin
            P := P + 1;
            if C = Feoln[0] then begin
                if high(Feoln) > 0 then begin
                    blockread(F,D,1,R);
                    if (R <> 0) then begin
                        if D = Feoln[1] then begin
                            endline := true;
                            P := P + 1; end
                        else
                            seek(F, P);
                    end else
                        P := P + 1;
                end else
                    endline := true;
            end else
                 S := S + chr(C);
            endfile := P = (filesize(F));
        end;
    until
        (endline = true) or (endfile = true);
    Feof := endfile;
end;

{$endif}
{}
...
{}
        close(PdfTmp);
{$ifdef OSX}
        reset(PdfTmp);
        while not eof(PdfTmp) do begin
            readln(PdfTmp,InpLine);
            putpdfln(InpLine);
        end;
        close(PdfTmp);
{$endif}
{$ifdef WIN}
        assign(PdfWrk,FileID+'.$$$'); {same file as PdfTmp}
        starttext(PdfWrk,eofPdfWrk);
        while not eofPdfWrk do begin
            gettext(PdfWrk, [13,10], eofPdfWrk, InpLine);
            putpdfln(InpLine);
        end;
        close(PdfWrk);
{$endif}
{}
...
```

I abandoned the idea that Windows was a viable product when I realized Microsoft had failed to follow IBM's instructions for how to handle interrupts which they published with the first IBM-PC. This failure still plagues the monstrous ill-conceived class structure of Windows; and leads to that enigmatic occasional glitch we've all experienced in Windows applications.

Personally, I don't believe an operating system should be built with classes, which impose an unnecessary overhead for process code that will be needed only once in the system (which if properly done will be true for all the code in the OS). A good API would suffice.